# sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm running a setup of FastAPI and SQLAlchemy to have a web server that runs basic CRUD operations. After a certain time the server is up in a docker container I get the following error message

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back
FROM users 
WHERE users.email = %s]
[parameters: [immutabledict({})]]
INFO:- "POST /routename HTTP/1.0" 500 Internal Server Error
2020-11-23T11:54:38.764592599Z ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
```

Now to my knowledge, the issue is related to sessions and sessions closing.

Here's the route in question

```
@app.post('/routename')
async def getLogin(request: GetLoginRequest):
    ...
    what it does here it just fetches the current user and verifies by come parameters
    ...
    session.close()
    return JSONResponse(content=currentUser)
```

I don't know why it crashes despite having the `session.close()` at the end.

I define my session in the root of the application

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = settings.connection_string

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

Session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
session = Session()

Base = automap_base()
```

I honestly believe this is just a SQLAlchemy session issue and not a FASTApi issue, but I can't crack what's wrong and why it keep crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error running as a long session waiting for data.
My solution:

```
 try:
    session.close()
 except:
    session.rollback()
    session.close()
```